# Bhattacharya Distance on Distributions (Matrices) with Different Number of Variables (Dimensions)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, mahalanobis-distance

We have two matrices, $A$ and $B$, representing two different probability distributions, with dimensions, $m*n$ and $k*n$, respectively.

How can we calculate the Bhattacharya distance or another measure of similarity or dissimilarity between $A$ and $B$?

Here, $m$ and $k$ denote the number of variables captured by the two matrices $A$ and $B$. In general, $m$ and $k$ are not equal.

$n$ is the number of observations, which is the same across the two distributions.

**Related Broader Question:**

[Bhattacharya Distance (or A Measure of Similarity) --- On Matrices with Different Dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616453/bhattacharya-distance-or-a-measure-of-similarity-on-matrices-with-differen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Johnson Lindenstrauss transformation, we can reduce the dimensions of the larger dataset to be the same dimension as the smaller dataset and then compute the Bhattacharya Distance.

Link: "[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson–Lindenstrauss_lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma)"